# Why Azure Redis Cache on asp.net use only few connected client of 1000 and throw timeout error?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-redis-cache

In the last days i'm trying to optimize my website due low performance casued by redis cache when i have a peak of connection.

I'm using redis version **1.2.6** and i have set **abortConnect=false** in connection string.

here how i get the connection to redis:

```
private static readonly Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> LazyConnection
  = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() => 
ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(GetRedisConnectionString()));

private static readonly Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> LazyConnection
  = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
  {
      var connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(GetRedisConnectionString());
      connection.PreserveAsyncOrder = false;
      //connection.TimeoutMilliseconds
      return connection;
  });
```

In global.asax i've changed the min Threads as suggested in this article http://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts

```
    int workerThreads = 500;
    int iocpThreads = 500;

    System.Threading.ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(workerThreads, iocpThreads)
```

But we still have some error like this one in log:

```
Timeout performing GET campaign_url_728566_288, inst: 19, mgr: Inactive, 
err: never, queue: 7, qu: 0, qs: 7, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 0, ar: 0, 
clientName: RD00155D881345, serverEndpoint: 
Unspecified/**********************, keyHashSlot: 6859, IOCP: 
(Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=500,Max=1000), WORKER: 
(Busy=25,Free=8166,Min=500,Max=8191)
```

or

```
Timeout performing GET campaign_url_728566_288, inst: 7, mgr: Inactive, err: 
never, queue: 24, qu: 0, qs: 24, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 4488, ar: 0, 
clientName: RD00155D881345, serverEndpoint: Unspecified**********, 
keyHashSlot: 6859, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=500,Max=1000), WORKER: 
(Busy=40,Free=8151,Min=500,Max=8191)
```

Now i notice that the max connection created and showed in the portal are max 20, when i expect to have more than them during high volume.
[image: azure redis connection]

Is there any setting to increase the number of connection from ConnectionMultiplexer? Or the problem is related to the size of the cache (currently C1 standard) or due limited bandwidth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such issues can be caused by Server or Client side issues. Have you looked into https://gist.github.com/JonCole/db0e90bedeb3fc4823c2#file-diagnoserediserrors-clientside-md and https://gist.github.com/JonCole/9225f783a40564c9879d#file-diagnoserediserrors-serverside-md?

If you send us the following information (https://gist.github.com/JonCole/132b255425268459ec95#file-supportquestionnaire-md) at azurecache@microsoft.com, we can investigate as well to see if there are any bottlenecks on the server and what recommendations we might have.

Comment: Having more connections may not fix your timeout errors - it will depend on the actual cause of the timeout.  The docs that Carl linked to describe the most common causes of timeouts.  Given that StackExchange.Redis supports pipelining, you don't generally have to increase the number of connections in order to get good throughput.  StackExchange.Redis does not use connection pooling under the covers.  However, if you want to try adding more connections, you can do so by creating a pool of ConnectionMultiplexer objects, then distributing requests to different multiplexers.

Comment: It was definetely a problem related to CPU client that reach 100%. We move from 20 request/sec to 500 request/sec . One soultion is to horizontal scale our client. Do you think that also reducing the timeout from 5000 to 500ms-1 sec will be a good idea for optimization(consider that the page is used to track click and then redirect to a link stored in redis )?

Comment: For small data values, of up to the size 1KB or slightly more, a 1 sec timeout is usually sufficient. That's also the default value. Setting it lower than 1 second doesn't mean that the requests will complete any sooner even though most requests should complete is much less than that. So having it be around 1 sec should help you in the situation where a network blip or something causes a single request to take longer and timeout. Also, do ensure that you are usually running somewhere close to say 50% CPU, so there is room for CPU bursts, the same for threadpool.